# Accessing music library and playlists on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, playlist

On iPhone, I'd like to be able to allow the user to select a song from their iTunes library.
Also, I was wondering how an app can access the specific playlist that song resides in (and how my app can access other songs in that playlist).

Answer (score 1):

Since you've asked a fairly open question, all I can suggest is have a look at the [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to get started and then come back with a more detailed question after you've tried some thing.